# Referring to Child Properties in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

New to Ractive.js and after reading over the docs I'm still hung up on some of the syntax. My example below creates a canvas tag for **each** element in my array and then instantiates a **distinct** object of a custom class for each to handle the animation. As noted in comments, I'm throwing three errors.

In the event handler I want to refer to the height property (defined in my array), but neither this.get(repeater.height) nor this.repeater.height work. I also want to call a method of the object associated with that event, but using this.myCustomClass.setFrame() isn't working either.

I'm also getting at least one error in the code for my animation class when I try to refer to methods of the canvas: this.canvas.getContext() **where "canvas" is the id I passed in the object constructor.**

So clearly I'm misunderstanding something about how to refer to child properties of Ractive instances. Any help here?

```
var repeater = [
    {id: "stalkerOne", width: 225, height: 432, left: 8, spriteSheetURL: "spriteSheets/stalkerone.jpg", rows: 5, columns: 5, totalFrames:  24},
    {id: "stalkerTwo", width: 175, height: 432, left: 230, spriteSheetURL: "spriteSheets/stalkertwo.jpg", rows: 6, columns: 5, totalFrames:  26},
    {id: "stalkerThree", width: 251, height: 432, left: 404, spriteSheetURL: "spriteSheets/stalkerthree.jpg", rows: 6, columns: 5, totalFrames:  28}
]

var CanvasAnimation = Ractive.extend( {
    oninit: function() {
        this.get('repeaters').forEach(function(repeater){
            var myCanvasSprite = new CanvasSprite(repeater.id, repeater.width, repeater.height, repeater.spriteSheetURL, repeater.rows, repeater.columns, repeater.totalFrames);
            myCanvasSprite.setFrame(0);
            //this.canvas.getContext() throwing error in class code
        });

        this.on('setFrame', function (event) {
            var offsetY = event.original.clientY - event.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var relY = offsetY/this.get(repeater.height); //why doesn't this.get() work here?
            this.myCanvasSprite.setFrame(relY); //custom class method not working either...
        });
    }
});       

var canvasAnimation = new CanvasAnimation({
    el: '#container',
    template: '#template',
    data: { repeaters: repeater }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing is adding the array of CanvasSprite objects to the Ractive data, and then using the event context to get the current sprite (see https://jsfiddle.net/martypdx/srbvekc4/2/ for full example):

```
var CanvasAnimation = Ractive.extend( {
    template: `
        {{#each sprites}}
            <li on-click='setFrame'>{{.id}}</li>
        {{/each}}`,
    oninit() {
        var sprites = this.get('repeaters').map( function(repeater){    
            return new CanvasSprite(repeater.id, repeater.width, repeater.height, repeater.spriteSheetURL, repeater.rows, repeater.columns, repeater.totalFrames);
        });

        // add the class instances to the data
        this.set( 'sprites', sprites );

        this.on('setFrame', function (event) {
            // here's how we get the sprite from the event
            var sprite = event.context;
            var offsetY = event.original.clientY - event.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var relY = offsetY/sprite.height;
            sprite.setFrame(relY);
        });
    },
    onrender() {
        // wait till render, otherwise nothing there!
        this.get( 'sprites' ).forEach( sprite => sprite.setFrame(0) );
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** You can also use components to better encapsulate each sprite (see https://jsfiddle.net/martypdx/srbvekc4/1/):

```
var CanvasAnimation = Ractive.extend( {
    template: `
        {{#each repeater}}
            <Sprite options='{{this}}'></Sprite>
        {{/each}}`
});    

var Sprite = Ractive.extend({
    template: `<li on-click='setFrame'>{{sprite.id}}</li>`,
    oninit() {
        const sprite = new CanvasSprite( repeater.id, repeater.width, repeater.height, repeater.spriteSheetURL, repeater.rows, repeater.columns, repeater.totalFrames );

        // since example template is using properties from sprite,
        // we add it to the data
        this.set( 'sprite',  sprite );

        this.on('setFrame', function (event) {
            var offsetY = event.original.clientY - event.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var relY = offsetY/sprite.height;
            sprite.setFrame(relY);
        });
    },
    onrender() {
        this.sprite.setFrame(0);
    }
});

var canvasAnimation = new CanvasAnimation({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: { repeaters: repeater },
    components: { Sprite }
});
```

UPDATED: Use multi-parameter constructor and also realized better encapsulation if component handles instantiation of `CanvasSprite`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's a much more elegant solution and I see my problem in terms of adding my objects to the Ractive data. Except...you changed the constructor to take an array and that's not an option for me here since I'm using that code in dozens of other projects. My kneejerk response is to overload the constructor to take an array, but I know I can't do that in Javascript. Any idea how to do this and still pass it individual arguments? (using your first example here for brevity, btw)

Comment: Tried something like this, but it's not working: `var canvasSprites= [];
        canvasSprites.push(this.get('repeaters').forEach(function(repeater){
            new CanvasSprite(repeater.id, repeater.width, repeater.height, repeater.spriteSheetURL, repeater.rows, repeater.columns, repeater.totalFrames);
        }));
        this.set({canvasSprites});`

Comment: Oh, you can change the constructor to whatever you want. In this example it's an object, not an array. I'll update the example to how you had it, and would it be clearer for you without the ES2015 syntax?

Comment: I updated the sample above, as well as the first jsfiddle to use the multi-arg constructor.

Comment: Ugh no, it's just late here. Not sure what I was thinking. I use ES5 syntax just because I'm not using babel everywhere, but actually prefer ES6 so no worries. But I'm still getting errors whenever I try to call methods from my objects... I have no idea why sprite.setFrame() isn't working since I define it the same as you do: `CanvasSprite.prototype.setFrame = function(frame) {
 this.frame = frame; 
};`

Comment: For reference, the code where it works: `var main = document.querySelector('#repeater');
var demo = new CanvasSprite(main, 225, 432,"../spriteSheets/stalkerone.jpg", 5, 5, 24);

var mouseY = 0;
getMouseScreen = function(event){
 mouseY = event.clientY/window.innerHeight;
 demo.setFrame(mouseY);
};`

Comment: Is the method getting divorced from the object by being passed as a parameter? IOW, are you calling `sprite.setFrame(y)` directly or indirectly?

What's the error your getting? If you `console.log(sprite)` and inspect does that yield any info?

Comment: Sorry, commented too soon. Your naming conventions through me off (my fault, since you have no idea what my class does). I believe the issue was primarily because I didn't update my template. And now they're not working? Like `{{#each sprites}}
<li>{{.id}}</li>
{{/each}}` just renders the bullet points and not the ids...

Comment: I should add I'm still confused by your naming conventions. You define "sprite" as a local variable in the event handler and then try to call it inside onrender(). You jsfiddle doesn't check to see whether that line is doing anything and when I do try to print to the console inside onrender() it does in fact tell me sprite is undefined. FYI, I'm using the mustache notation from your jsfiddle (`this.set({sprites})` ) instead of `this.set('sprites', sprite)` since that also references an undefined variable. I think this might be the root of the problem, but not sure.

Comment: Can you paste your block of code from assignment of the `sprites` variable to the set call?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's all just one line of code in my animation class that obviously wouldn't work when encapsulated like this. What I'm trying to do should be fairly evident: `var context = this.id.getContext('2d')`

Comment: In other words, when using Ractive.extend() how does one refer to DOM elements since document.getElementById() obviously doesn't work? Maybe instead of passing my constructor the id I can call it after rendering and pass it Ractive.findComponent('id')? Would that work?

Comment: You know what, I'm going to ask a new question for this since I think it warrants it and I've already marked this one answered. Please feel free to answer my new question, though :)