# How to refer to DOM Elements When Using Ractive.extend()?

Tags: javascript, dom, ractivejs

So if I'm using Ractive.extend() to instantiate objects of a custom class then how would I go about referring to DOM elements inside that class? I obviously can't use document.getElementById() as usual since the DOM hasn't been rendered yet and passing Ractive.findComponent() to my constructor returns "Ractive.findComponent is not a function." What I want to do is something like this:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(id /*,...*/) {
        this.element = document.getElementById(id); //how do I do this??
    };
};

var Extended = Ractive.extend( {
    oninit() {
        var myObject = new myClass(id /*,...*/);
        this.set({myObject});
    } 
});

var ractiveExtended = new Extended({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: { id: myId}
});
```

ETA: This doesn't work either...

```
class myClass {
    constructor(id /*,...*/) {
        this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    };
};

var Extended = Ractive.extend( {
    onrender() {
        var myObject = new myClass(id /*,...*/);
        this.set({myObject});
    } 
});

var ractiveExtended = new Extended({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: { id: myId}
});
```

And neither does this...

```
class myClass {
    constructor(id /*,...*/) {
        this.element = id;
        this.element.innerHTML = 'Hello world!';
    };
};

var Extended = Ractive.extend( {
    onrender() {
        var myObject = new myClass(document.getElementById(id) /*,...*/);
        this.set({myObject});
    } 
});

var ractiveExtended = new Extended({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: { id: myId}
});
```

Comment: How tied are you to passing in an `id` to your CanvasSprint class versus passing in the canvas node directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Full running example available at: http://jsbin.com/vuziyepeku/edit?html,js,output

I would encapsulate each `CanvasSprite` in it's own component:

```
const CanvasSpriteComponent = Ractive.extend({

    template: '#sprite',

    // Using onrender, not oninit, because we need DOM canvas node
    onrender(){
        const canvas = this.find('canvas');
        const repeater = this.get('repeater');

        var sprite = new CanvasSprite(canvas, repeater.width, repeater.height, repeater.spriteSheetURL, repeater.rows, repeater.columns, repeater.totalFrames);
        sprite.left = repeater.left; //add variables *not* in the constructor
        sprite.setFrame(0);

        this.on('setFrame', function (event) {
            var offsetY = event.original.clientY - event.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var relY = offsetY/sprite.height;
            sprite.setFrame(relY);
        });
    }
});
```

Then use it in the main instance:

```
var CanvasAnimation = Ractive.extend( {
    template: '#animation',
    components: {
        'canvas-sprite': CanvasSpriteComponent
    }   
});

var canvasAnimation = new CanvasAnimation({
    el: 'main',
    data: { repeaters: repeater }
});
```

Arguably it makes more sense for your `CanvasSprite` class to take a canvas node because then it is no longer tied to *how* that node is located (currently `document.getElementById`).

If you're not willing to change that class at all, you just need to make up a unique id (or use the index if the repeater collection is not going to mutate). In this case I'm reusing the component's unique id:

```
const CanvasSpriteComponent = Ractive.extend({
    // ...
    onrender(){
        const canvas = this.find('canvas');
        canvas.id = `canvas-${this._guid}`
        const repeater = this.get('repeater');

        var sprite = new CanvasSprite(canvas.id, repeater.width, repeater.height, repeater.spriteSheetURL, repeater.rows, repeater.columns, repeater.totalFrames);
        sprite.left = repeater.left; //add variables *not* in the constructor
        sprint.setFrame(0);

        this.on('setFrame', function (event) {
            var offsetY = event.original.clientY - event.node.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            var relY = offsetY/sprite.height;
            sprite.setFrame(relY);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Marty! This is a pretty good answer, although obviously cribbed from my ridiculously extended comment thread with MartIN...which is quite fitting since I'm beginning to see you two as transatlantic doppelgangers of one another :) I think I'll just mark both of them as answered (if that's possible?) and let more experience SO users decide who gets upvoted to the top.

Comment: I definitely agree on both points that I should be using components for this and that it makes sense for me to modify my constructor to take a canvas node since that arguably makes it _less_ implementation specific rather than moreso. And I suppose that's also the only reason to instantiate my objects in onrender() rather than oninit() as I'm currently doing.

Comment: Ugh, this isn't working. I copied your code verbatim (minus the typo..."sprint") and updated the CanvasSprite class accordingly. It looks like the components aren't even rendering. I think it might have to do with your second template. I tried writing it inline as in the docs instead of using Ractive.extend() twice and when I change the template to `{{#each repeater} <li>{{.}}"></li>{{/each}}` I just get one line of text reading "template." Also, should the component name be in quotes like you have it here: `components: { 'canvas-sprite': CanvasSpriteComponent }`? The docs have no quotes.

Comment: I think I spotted my typo in the template, should be plural `{{#each repeaters}}`.

Comment: @Sophia I added a link to jsbin that has the code running

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer to the problem clarified in the comments**

You've got a little chicken-egg problem here:

```html
{{#each sprites}}
    <canvas id={{.id}}></canvas>
{{/each}}
```

means Ractive will create a `<canvas>` for each item in `sprites` and assign it the appropriate ID. However, `sprites` is undefined on initial render, so no `<canvas>` elements are created.

Then, inside `onrender()` you create instances of your class, which assume the `<canvas>` elements are already there. Only after that you add the instances to `sprites`, telling Ractive to render the elements:

```js
this.set({ sprites });
```

There are several possible solutions. The (I think) best would be adding a `render()` method to your class and moving anything DOM-related out of constructor. Your code would then change to something like this:

```js
onrender () {
    var sprites = this.get('repeaters').map(function(repeater){    
        return new CanvasSprite(repeater.id);
    });

    this.set({ sprites });

    sprites.forEach(function (sprite) {
        sprite.render();
    });
}
```

However, if you don't want to modify your class, you can simply use the existing `repeaters` array for the `{{each}}` loop. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9xLzj3zd/1/

The point is, you need a way to tell Ractive to render the `<canvas>` elements before you use `document.getElementsById()` or similar methods.

**Original answer**

If you need to access the DOM, move the initialization code from `oninit` to `onrender`. Then you can use either `document.getElementById()` or `ractive.find()` ([documentation here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/0.7/ractive-find)) to get the elements you want.

```
class myClass {
    constructor(id) {
        this.element = document.getElementById(id);
        this.element.innerHTML = 'Hello world!';
    };
};

var Extended = Ractive.extend( {
    onrender() {
        // use this.get('id') to get ID from Ractive's data
        var myObject = new myClass(this.get('id'));
        this.set({myObject});
    } 
});

var ractiveExtended = new Extended({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template',
    data: { id: 'content' },
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgpe2h5L/1/

Comment: That doesn't work. If I call document.getElementById(this.id) inside the class it returns null. Same with document.querySelector(this.id). And I already explained the error I get from Ractive.findComponent(). Those both occur whether I instantiate the object after rendering or not.

Comment: Check if the values of `this.id` and the element's ID match - it should definitely work. As for `find()` - it's an instance method, so make sure you call it on your ractive instance (`ractiveExtended`), not the global Ractive variable.

Comment: Yup, made sure of that: this.id matches the id. Thanks for explaining find(), though. But if I have to call it in the Ractive instance then I can't pass it to the constructor... I could write a method to do that, but the point is really not to have to modify my class just to work with a specific framework.

Comment: Then there must be something else wrong with your code. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgpe2h5L/ - it clearly works there.

Comment: Except your jsfiddle isn't an example of what I'm trying to do at all. Using my example code, can you show document.getElementById() either working _inside_ the object or passed as an argument in the constructor in a manner that allows me to access properties of the element inside the object?

Comment: It shows `document.getElementById()` works, which is the only point. If it works there, it's going to work anywhere else in your code.

Comment: I edited my question to demonstrate exactly where in my code it's not working. All return "cannot read property 'x' of null."

Comment: I updated my answer - see the comment about `this.get('id')`, which may be the reason it didn't work before.

Comment: Just saw that. But in my actual project I don't need this.get() since I'm using map() with arrays. So the actual initialization goes like `var myObjects = this.get(‘ids’).map(function(myIds){ return new myClass(myIds.id); });`. You can see the full example (minus the class itself) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142915/referring-to-child-properties-in-ractive-js.

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter where the ID comes from, as long as it's correct. Important thing is my demo still works, even after I changed it to use your code. If you can update my jsfiddle so that it stops working, we might be able to this out. Otherwise I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: Now I see where's the problem. See the updated answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is a great explanation I feel like should be tagged "best of Ractive.js" or something like that. As far as a solution though...I gather the first method isn't viable since it would require entirely rewriting my class just for one framework? For clarification all DOM references are in methods meant to be called in event handlers, not the constructor, so in my actual project they're already only being called _after_ `this.set({ sprites });` yet I get the DOM errors nonetheless...

Comment: As for the second method...it just seems sloppy, but beyond that it for some reason doesn't allow me access to my class methods. I'm not sure why, but when I change `{{#each sprites}}` to `{{#each repeaters}}` in the template I can't call `sprite.setFrame()` in `onrender()`. So I understand the problem now, but am confused as to why neither solution is working for me. The full code with event handlers is in the other question I linked to above.

Comment: Probably best is to check out Marty's example: https://jsfiddle.net/martypdx/srbvekc4/2/ and change `{{#each sprites}}` to `{{#each repeaters}}`. It prints to console so you can see my method works the first time when I have it set to zero for each object, but throws an error when used in the event handler. This makes sense this the event handler is now linked to the repeaters array instead of the sprites array that holds the objects.

Comment: You get the error because of `this.element = document.getElementById(id)` in constructor - the element doesn't exist,  so it's set to `null` and then (probably in other methods) you try to call methods of the non-existing element. You'd only need to refactor the constructor, so that it set's `this.element` correctly. No other methods would need to be modified.

Comment: Marty's code relies on the context (see the JS line #28), so it depends on what you pass to {{#each}}. However, it can be fixed easily: https://jsfiddle.net/srbvekc4/3/

Comment: So both solutions work; #1 is more clear, but requires some changes to the existing code (the changes wouldn't make your code Ractive specific though), #2 might not be that nice, but it's easy, fast, and works.

Comment: Oh wow, that `setFrame:{{sprites[@index]}`is really some magic I didn't know I could do. Everything is working now, I just need to fix the math so it's clipping and scaling the sprites correctly. I'm still confused as to why I needed to go this route, though. In my actual class I'm currently just storing the id in the constructor and then calling document.getElementById() each time setFrame() is called. So I see how this could be a problem when I zero it out initially, but when I call setFrame() in the event handler my understanding is the canvases should be rendered by then.

Comment: Commented before seeing your update... I agree #1 is much better coding style, but as I explained above I'm actually already doing it that way and still getting errors from the event handler. Check out lines 17 and 18: https://jsfiddle.net/48287gtz/.

Comment: I tried this another way (https://jsfiddle.net/zr7kcurf/) and it seems to be a problem that only applies to `canvas.getContext()`. Seems if I was trying to reference another DOM element my code would have worked perfectly as is and no need to have asked this question. Now I'm scratching my head even more...

Comment: The linked fiddle is using `<li>` instead of `<canvas>`, and `<li>` doesn't have `getContext()`. Also, the LIs were missing the ID attributes. After fixing those two things, it actually works without any workarounds: https://jsfiddle.net/48287gtz/2/

Comment: Exactly, it was caused by `canvas.getContext()`. Check my comment above.

Comment: Yeah, I worked that out in the meantime. I can't tell what's different with my actual code, but I just forked the fiddle with it if you want to take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/trrenL7v/3/. Obviously the images don't load, but you can see that error is still there...

Comment: Inside your class, you store the ID in `canvas` property, but in the Ractive template, you refer to it as `id`, which is `undefined`. Either use `canvas` inside Ractive, or `id` inside your class.

Comment: It's not a property, it's just the variable name. Shouldn't that be irrelevant since they're all local? I'm confused as to why I can't have a constructor `function CanvasSprite(canvas) {this.canvas = canvas;}` and then instantiate it like `new CanvasSprite(id)` and have `this.canvas == id`.

Comment: Line #3 in HTML. It's accessing `id` property of your class, but the property is called `canvas` there.

Comment: In the html? At no point did I have something like `<canvas canvas={{.id}}>`. Anyway, I updated the fiddle instead of forking it. As you suggested I changed ALL the variables in every scope to be just `id`. Now it's just rendering one canvas tag with default properties and Ractive is throwing a bunch of errors that the element is broken: https://jsfiddle.net/trrenL7v/7/.

Comment: I'm just very confused because you first said it was due to the naming of local variables inside my class not matching with local variables inside Ractive and now you're saying it's because I misnamed the id property in the html. I added a border to the canvases so you can now see how they're drawn regardless of whether the animation is working. Locally, method #1 seems to be drawing only one canvas or possibly layering them on top of one another. Method #2  _looks_ right, but when I query the width and height from the canvases they're all 150 and 300 instead of what's in my data array.

Comment: I think I'm spent for the day, but here are my two versions actually in full: [method #1](http://sretaeper.ucoz.com/stalker_Ractive/index_elegantMethod.html) seems to maybe be overlapping the three canvases so only the third one is visible and [method #2](http://sretaeper.ucoz.com/stalker_Ractive/index.html) seems to be working correctly except for a weird sizing glitch I commented in the animation engine. Of course, I haven't tried playing around with the size properties in my data array yet to see if it scales correctly...

Comment: Your HTML was `<canvas id={{.id}}>`, so you were trying yo read property `id` of `sprite`, but on `sprite` the property was called `canvas`. The error about element being broken has nothing to do with Ractive. That said, I think we've got well beyond the scope of the original question. SO is not really suited for long discussions like this. If you have any more problems, please always open a question for each specific problem, or try opening an issue on GitHub, which is better for longer discussions.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for you help and I'll take this elsewhere. But as for the naming convention, the properties in sprites were mapped from my data array, which never contained a variable called "canvas." The parameter in my class's constructor that took the id was named "canvas," but that's entirely arbitrary unless there's something Ractive specific going on I'm not aware of. And anyway, none of those corrections resulted in a properly rendering template so going to have to look over my code with fresh eyes and see if I could have actually found a bug.

Comment: Martin, I figured out the problem with the more elegant method! I was hardcoding `position:absolute` into my canvas css and that doesn't play nicely with Ractive for reasons I don't understand technically, but sort of makes sense. This was causing the canvases to be drawn on top of one another instead of positioned with the css `left` attribute. Now just trying to figure out why with both methods the canvases are being sized at 150x300 instead of with the value in my data array...

Comment: Correction... `position:absolute' was a red herring, the real problem was I never loaded my `left` property into the new data array since I had no need for it in the constructor! Fixed that. Then the size issue is that I was confusing canvas width and height properties for _drawing_ with the CSS properties of the same name used to scale it. Currently I'm setting them both to my data values in the template, but may want CSS scaling in future variations...exactly the flexibility I wanted out of Ractive! I finally have perfectly working code :D Now to compare CPU profiles...

Comment: I'd like to mark this as answered since you really helped me out along the way, but neither your original answer nor the edited version get at the problem. I moved my instantiation back to `oninit()` since I think that makes more sense, although it runs the same either way. And the "chicken and the egg" rendering turned out not to be the issue either since my class doesn't refer to the canvases until after rendering. It all came down to some silly errors in templating and naming conventions so not sure if you can easily update your answer, but if so definitely let me know.

Comment: I *could* update the answer, but I don't see a reason to do so. Both methods *do* fix the problem with the code you provided in the question. The reason why the final solution is different is that you provided different code in the question that what you actually use (e.g. you *did* use `document.getElementById()` inside constructor in the SO question). For anybody looking into "How to refer to DOM Elements When Using Ractive.extend()", my answer is correct.

Comment: That's fair. My thinking was since I already knew the likely method to call (`document.getElementById()`) it would have been obvious I was looking for a more general answer about referring to DOM elements inside encapsulated code rather than something like, "Here's a totally different example using that method, which proves it does work in all cases." After all, it obviously _doesn't_ work if the scope is incorrect and node or reference to the node isn't passed correctly.

Comment: Also why I generally avoid using lengthy and specific code examples on SO is because it tends to create more confusion than it resolves. For example, when I pasted my class into a jsfiddle you initially said the problem was calling `document.getElementById()` in the constructor (I wasn't) then that the problem was the names of my constructor's parameters not matching those of the arguments I was passing to it as well as the local variables they were stored as when obviously parameter names don't matter. So I surely could have asked this better, but probably not by including the entire class.